# ODE: Peano existence theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to show that $ y^\prime = \sqrt{|x|+|y|}$, defined on $\mathbb R^2$ has a solution through $(0,0)$.

Isn‘t this trivial by using the peano existence theorem? Since the exercise is graded with many points, I assume that I miss something because „Follows directly from the peano existence theorem“ seems not to be the solution…

What is the difficulty here?

Comment: It's true that by Peano the Cauchy problem $\begin{cases}y'=\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert}\\ y(0)=0\end{cases}$ has a solution in a neighbourhood of $0$. As an external observer I can't quite know if they have demands on the domain, or if they don't expect people to use Peano, or what.

Comment: With Peano there is no difficulty since the RHS is clearly continuous in $x$ and $y$. Without Peano, different story

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem now: Not the existence of some solution is to show but the existence of a solution defined on $\mathbb R$. Can maybe someone give me a hint how to start here? Separation doesn’t work, finding a primitive seems difficult…